# C# assigning elements of a list to a list of variables

Tags: c#, list

In Perl one can do the following

```
($a, $b, $c) = split(',', "aaa,bbb,ccc");
```

does anyone know if there is an equivalent in C# other than doing the following?

```
var elements = "aaa,bbb,ccc".Split(',');
var a = elements[0];
var b = elements[1];
var c = elements[2];
```

Or is there an alternative for doing the above more concisely?

Comment: `Divide and conquer` is one of the best aspects of languages like C#.

Comment: What you're doing in Perl is wasteful. You're performing a `split` operation completely unnecessarily just to eliminate two short lines of code, thereby obfuscating your code in the process.

Comment: and that is why Perl is often described as a write-only language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no other way to do this in C#.
But there is hope in .net - namely F# :D
With this you could do

```
let [| a; b; c |] = "aaa,bbb,ccc".Split(',')
```

Comment: as a side note: never mind the warning this kind of code will produce in F# - the compiler is just *carefull* :P

Answer (score 3):

No. There's no way of assigning more than one variable in a single assignment expression in C#. Do you definitely need separate variables instead of an array?

Perhaps if you gave us the wider context, we may be able to suggest a better approach to the overall problem - often if you try to approach a task in the way that you would in a different language, you end up with messy code, and that may be the case here.

Comment: And as a personal comment, I'd say that's a good thing. It's consistent with C#'s general style: as concise as possible without ambiguity. Multiple variable assignment in a single expression is fun for reducing lines of code, but it's harder to pick up someone else's code and read it that way (IMO).

Comment: There is no wider context in this instance.  It's just something that has cropped up from time to time and I thought I'd find out if it was possible.

Comment: @Scroog1: But every specific instance would have had its own context, and may have been better approached in alternative ways.

Answer (score 0):

Still not a perfect solution but with C# 7 we can use tuple deconstruction:

```
var elements = "aaa,bbb,ccc".Split(',');
var (a, b, c) = (elements[0], elements[1], elements[2]);
```